# What's the purpose of the paged.php file?

Tags: templates

In context of the template hierarchy chart? From what i gather, the paged.php file is something to do with an archive?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we look in `template-loader.php`, we can see the conditions under which `paged.php` will be loaded:

```
if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES ) :
    $template = false;
    if     ( is_404()            && $template = get_404_template()            ) :
    elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()         ) :
    elseif ( is_tax()            && $template = get_taxonomy_template()       ) :
    elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
    elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
    elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()     ) :
        remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
    elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()         ) :
    elseif ( is_page()           && $template = get_page_template()           ) :
    elseif ( is_category()       && $template = get_category_template()       ) :
    elseif ( is_tag()            && $template = get_tag_template()            ) :
    elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()         ) :
    elseif ( is_date()           && $template = get_date_template()           ) :
    elseif ( is_archive()        && $template = get_archive_template()        ) :
    elseif ( is_comments_popup() && $template = get_comments_popup_template() ) :
    elseif ( is_paged()          && $template = get_paged_template()          ) :
    else :
        $template = get_index_template();
    endif;
    if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) )
        include( $template );
    return;
endif;
```

The last `elseif` is where the paged template is loaded if it exists:

```
elseif ( is_paged()          && $template = get_paged_template()          ) :
```

Which means that all of the checks above have to return false for the `paged.php` template to be loaded, the query `is_paged` and no other more content-specific template was found.

Comment: I think, paged.php can be used to customize paged pages - page/2/ etc.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14779#comment:4

Comment: yes, that's what `is_paged()` means, however if any other more specific template is available, that template will be called before `paged.php`. for example, if your theme has an `archive.php` template, `paged.php` will never be used for any type of content that uses `archive.php`, regardless of page number.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, if you have `paged.php` present in your theme, that template will be used for all but the first page of the archive. This is in case the styling/markup for your archive is drastically different between the first page, and subsequent pages.

Comment: this isn't entirely accurate, if a more specific template like `archive.php` or `category.php` exists, `paged.php` will not be used. only if there's just an `index.php` template will `paged.php` take precedence.

Comment: You're absolutely, right - you stop at the first available template on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of WP 4.7 paged.php has been removed from the template loader altogether and thus the template hierarchy.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/38755