# Wordpress loading index page instead of archive.php

Tags: pagination, archives

I have

```
index.php
archive.php
...
```

When I go to domain.com, it loads index.php, which is expected.

But, when I go `www.domain.com/page/2/`, it loads the correct posts (as in, the posts in the second page), but uses in **index.php template**. I want to load the **archive.php template**. How is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

`archive.php` is not used for subsequent pages of non-search, non-taxonomy, ... based subsets of content.

I think you might be looking for `paged.php` (but that'll also be used for the first page).

Alternatively add logic to `index.php` to call a different template where page number is greater than one.

***Correction*** on reviewing http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview `pages.php` is not the answer. Paged (ie. not single) posts use `home.php` otherwise `index.php` only.

So you'll need to put in your own logic (presumably to `home.php`) to use `index.php` or some custom template for posts.

(This [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58175/256) shows the WP logic to decide which template to use.)

Comment: Yes thanks that's what I eded up doing. I just used if .. else

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do this, as it is not a native feature of WP.

Basically, check if $paged is set, which you can do by calling is_paged() inside a conditional.

```
<?php if ( ! is_paged() ) : 
// code for home page 
else: 
// code for archive page
endif; 
?>
```

Making use of templates can make this index.php still look tidy/neat.

You're going to need to make sure you're doing this, though:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
```

Before either the home query or the archive query.